# unhover in raphaeljs not working

Tags: raphael

I'm currently applying anonymous functions to a hover event, that call global functions inside:

```
GridInterface.HexGrid.TileGlobal = {

hoverIn: function(obj) {
  var self = obj;
  self.tile.attr({ fill: '#c7c7c7', stroke : '#000' });
  self.tile.toFront();
  self.label.toFront();
  self.label.attr({ fill : '#000' });
},

hoverOut: function(obj) {
  var self = obj;
  self.tile.attr({ fill : '#d0d1ff', stroke : '#aaa' });
  self.label.attr({ fill: '#999' });
}
}
```

Then i simply call:

```
 .hover(function() {
        GridInterface.HexGrid.TileGlobal.hoverIn(self);
      }, function() {
        GridInterface.HexGrid.TileGlobal.hoverOut(self);
      }
    )
```

on the object. However, when i switch that to unhover, the event is not removed. I think it's because it's a different anonymous function. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315456/raphael-js-how-to-remove-events which describes the same issue, including hover, and has an answer with a working jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe solve the problem not with the raphäel event handling but with a library of your choice, ie jQuery: $(circle.node).click(…)

like that you can addEvent / removeEvent on demand.

Answer (score 1):

```
    GridInterface.HexGrid.Tile = function(coords) {

        var self = this;


        this.hoverIn = function() {
          this.attr({ fill: '#c7c7c7', stroke : '#000' });
        };

        this.hoverOut = function() {
          this.attr({ fill: '#d0d1ff', stroke: '#aaa' });
        };

        this.attachEvents = function()
        {
          self.el[0].hover(self.hoverIn, self.hoverOut);
        };
    };
```

Then elsewhere i call:

```
tile.el[0].unhover(tile.hoverIn, tile.hoverOut);
```

Tile being an object instance of that above function.