# Raphael JS : how to remove events?

Tags: events, mouseover, raphael

I use the Raphael .mouseover() and .mouseout() events to highlight some elements in my SVG. 
This works fine, but after I click on an element, I want it to stop highlighting.

In the [Raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#events) I found :

> To unbind events use the same method names with “un” prefix, i.e. element.unclick(f);

but I can't get this to work and I also don't understand the 'f' parameter.

This doesn't work , but what does??

```
obj.click( function() {
  this.unmouseover();
});
```

Comment: With 40 questions, I would hope more than 57% of them had appropriate answers that could be marked as correct. :)

Comment: No, the documentation says you can use 'un' to UNbind those events... but it doesn't work, or I'm doing something wrong... I'll check my questions again to select good answers, but most of them are really not fully answered yet, I think....

Comment: If you have a bunch of questions that have answers, but none of them are "right", then you might reconsider how you ask questions, whether they are clear and concise, and whether they are too localized to be answered successfully. :)

Comment: Also, if you provide a http://fiddle.net of your problem, that would probably help.

Comment: I think I just stumble upon difficult problems that I can't live with, while others accept them as normal annoyances... i'm not going to accept 'just live with it' as a good answer... check my unmarked questions, no real answers there... and I think there's not much wrong with my way of asking, even though english is not my first language...

Comment: I think fiddle.net is not the right url :)   (I'm not really into fiddle-music :)

Comment: I think it's kinda jamming. :P Try: http://jsfiddle.net/GexHj/

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. Even if I change the mouseover event to hover.  Does that 'un' even work in Raphael?  I don't see anybody here using that...

Comment: No, that fiddle was meant to demonstrate your problem, not solve it. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, what you have to do is pass the handler function to the `unmouseover` request:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

var mouseover = function (event) {
    this.attr({fill: "yellow"});
}
var mouseout = function (event) {
    this.attr({fill: "red"});
}

circle.hover(mouseover, mouseout);
circle.click(function (event) {
    this.attr({fill: "blue"});
    this.unmouseover(mouseover);
    this.unmouseout(mouseout);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GexHj/1/

That's what `f` is about. You can also use `unhover()`:

```
circle.click(function (event) {
    this.attr({fill: "blue"});
    this.unhover(mouseover, mouseout);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GexHj/2/

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!  Even got it working now with an array of objects, where I use the mouseout event as a 'property' of each object...

Comment: Question on this old answer: calling "this.unmouseout(mouseout);" seems to rely on the function name that you originally bound being "mouseout," right? So I could have called the function "myFunc" and I'd unbind it with "unmyFunc", right? But that seems horrible for any code minification, doesn't it? There's no guarantee at all that if "myFunc" gets minimized to "xy" that "unmyFunc" will be minimized to "unxy." Am I missing something?

Comment: `mouseout` is actually a reference to the function, not a string value. In theory, as passing a function by reference is part of the normal behavior in Javascript, an aggressive minification should identify and replace the function reference as well as the declaration of the function identifier label. My answer without any testing, you shouldn't have a problem. If you find a specific test with a specific minifier, please let me know.