# Raphael.js: How to unbind mousemove on set()?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have this code with Raphael.js:

```
var set = paper.set();
// ... here push some elements to set: path, circles, etc.
set.mousedown(function() { ... });
set.mousemove(function() { ... });
set.mouseup(function() { ... });
```

Everything works fine... but how to do `unbind` `.mousemove` event on "set" and `bind` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `un` before the event name http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.unmousemove

```
// Pass the handler to install it
set.mousemove(handler);
// Pass the same handler to remove it
set.unmousemove(handler);
```

[Raphael JS : how to remove events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315456/raphael-js-how-to-remove-events)

You can't pass in an anonymous function as you did, because you have to pass a reference to the function when removing a handler