# Discard a function or a .js file and its "effects"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using **AJAX** to change the content of my page, so each page has its own *functions* and *.js files*.

Therefore graph plugins load only in case there is a graph on the page, but these plugins look like they stay there until a refresh, which causes errors when the content changes and there are no graphs anymore on the page.

I'm using this code for my AJAX call (which I thought discards the functions and loaded plugins, but now it looks like it doesn't):

```
$.get(urlPath, function(html) {
    var doc = $(html);
    var currentScripts = $('.current-scripts'); // this is the div with plugins and functions for a specific page
    currentScripts.remove();
    currentScripts = undefined;
    $('.content').empty().css('opacity', '0').append(doc.children('.content >*'));
    $('.scripts').append(doc.children('.current-scripts'));
    ... // some more not related stuff
};
```

Now the problem is (and not only for this graphs plugin) that if a page loads **raphael.js** (a plugin) and **draws some graphs**, then when the content changes and there are no graphs and I **resize the browser** it gives me a bunch of errors linked to the fact that there are no graphs (or their container divs) on the page, but since the plugin and function were loaded, it still tries to draw them.
*(Editing the plugins isn't a good idea since it's a template and I have like 6 or 7 of them)*

**TL;DR**:
Is there a way to discard a plugin and some function in such a way, that every other event that was called by them is canceled (It stops trying to draw those graphs)?

Comment: `currentScripts.remove();` only removes the `script` tag but not the script that was loaded with/executed by this tag. Scripts will stay at least as long in memory as nothing is referencing them anymore. So you would need to add a _cleanup_ function to each of you plugins that has to be called by you if you unload them.

Comment: @t.niese that's what I'm searching for, can you please link me to such a **clean up** function ? I'm searching for two days and haven't seen anything that would help...

Comment: There are many ways to solve that and it heavily depends on your project structure, how you load/manage your scripts and how you organise your code. The probably best way would be to use a loader that support the `require` syntax, like webpack or requirejs, load your plugin with `currentPlugin = require('plugin-name'); currentPlugin.init();` and clean up the plugin (if it is set)  using `currentPlugin.cleanup()`

Comment: It's not enough to just remove functions. If the script set up event handlers, all those would need to be removed as well. You need to design your dynamic page so that each thing that gets loaded knows how to clean itself up. There's nothing built-in that does this.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315456/raphael-js-how-to-remove-events

Comment: @Barmar well I'm yet to find out how to do that, *but* is it possible to make **any plugin** that was loaded clean itself without specifying the functions/events it calls, in a small function or I would have to write a script that will be a few hundred lines long to do that?

Comment: No, there's no general-purpose way to do this. Every plugin design is different, the solution has to be tailored to it.